# Failed installing tensorflow==2.1.0 into Cloud Functions runtime Python 3.7

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to install tensorflow into Google Cloud Functions, but Failed to deploy like below error.

```
protoPayload: {
  @type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog"   
  authenticationInfo: {…}   
  methodName: "google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction"   
  requestMetadata: {…}   
  resourceName: "projects/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/functions/analyzepy"   
  serviceName: "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com"   
  status: {
   code: 3    
   message: "INVALID_ARGUMENT"    
  }
 }
```

What I did is; 
Adding `tensorflow==2.1.0` in Requirements.txt 
My runtime is Python 3.7 
Memory 256 MiB

Please advise how to install tensorflow on Cloud Functions.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `tensorflow==1.15`. Newer versions require AVX instructions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions#CPUs_with_AVX

Comment: Is that all the error output/information you have?

Comment: on [tensorflow-community-wheels](https://github.com/yaroslavvb/tensorflow-community-wheels/issues) you can find tensorflow precompiled for different computers/CPU - ie. without AVX

Comment: `tensorflow==1.15.0` did not work, still the same result. And this is an error code `Build failed: {"cacheStats": [{"status": "MISS", "hash": "2ee53d66db513630de091048f02b5319f58395b41082bbd1b1adb3b09b718582", "type": "docker_layer_cache", "level": "global"}, {"status": "MISS", "hash": "2ee53d66db513630de091048f02b5319f58395b41082bbd1b1adb3b09b718582", "type": "docker_layer_cache", "level": "project"}]}`

Comment: same situation here. Pipfile nor requirements.txt work